# Gmail IMAP in PHP works on localhost but not on a live domain

Tags: php, gmail, imap

My GMAIL IMAP code in PHP works great from my localhost but it doesn't work from domain.

I have done following items:

1) Allowed less secure apps to login
2) Enabled IMAP in GMAIL account
3) Two factor authentication is not enabled.
4) I have validated the account access too
5) I have also allowed this: http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Can it be the issue that I don't have SSL on the live server?

But I keep on getting this issue:

Cannot connect to Gmail: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco...

Comment: you solved it ? because i already have that issue.

Comment: Yes. I did it. Do you need any help on it?

Comment: Yes please. how can you did it ?

Comment: $connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'my_email_address', 'password_of_gmail') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

I used this code for connection and used PHP version 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Try This code. I am using this and my code was run both local and live .

https://codeshare.io/axMpZB

Comment: Getting below error :
Can't connect to imap.gmail.com,143: Network is unreachable